# can html point to JS object

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have html point to a javascript object?

I know I could have a hash in JS to associate the tag id (or some other attribute) with the JS object, but is there a way to add the pointer to the html tag to the JS object?

```
<div id="user10"></div>
<div id="user11"></div>
```

then in JS have

```
function getUserPointedByTag(tag){
    //this is what I would like to have without going through a hash
} 
function myAwesomeUserDivClickHandler(clickedTag){
    user = getUserPointedByTag(clickedTag)
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Do you mean you want something like `http://example.com/index.html?user=xx`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off using `data-` attributes to store the user ID in.

```
<div class="user" data-userid="10"></div>
<div class="user" data-userid="11"></div>
```

That way, you can easily retrieve the user ID associated with an element using:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var node = e.target.tagName ? e.target : e.target.parentNode;
    var userId = e.getAttribute("data-userid");
    // Do something with the user ID
}, false);
```

Comment: I suppose going though a hash to get the JS object is inevitable. -Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question several times i think this is what you want:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var node = e.target.tagName ? e.target : e.target.parentNode;
    yourAwesomeUserDivClickHandler(node);
}, false);
```